# Posting on Digg using .Net or PHP

Tags: .net, php, digg

I'm using Digg Api to get stories from digg. But I couldn't find any method to post stories on Digg using that API. Is there any other way to post stories on Digg?

Comment: I think that is by design.  They want to ensure bots aren't posting stories.  You can however do similar to "Digg this" buttons and link directly into the "New Story" submission process.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is by design, but you could likely do it using the [PHP curl libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)